# UDP tracker doesn't work with monotorrent client

Tags: c#, udp, monotorrent

As a part of my tcp chat file sharing I used monotorrent to build a udp tracker on the server program (of my chat) but the client (that I build with monotorrent) and the sample client on monotorrent's source code doesn't connect with the tracker, the port of the client and the server are open and Utorrent does connect with the tracker.

I also tried to use the sample tracker on the source code as a udp tracker but it didn't work.

This is what I changed (7243 = my tracker port):

```
        System.Net.IPEndPoint listenpoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, 7243);
        ListenerBase listener = new MonoTorrent.Tracker.Listeners.UdpListener(listenpoint);
```

Help please

Comment: Are you running both server and the client on the same machine?

Comment: yes but utorrent work's with the tracker.
Do you think i need to run it on a diffrent machine?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do and what "doesn't work". Try to re-phrase the question. Even better - try to come up with a minimal complete code example that shows the problem.

Comment: In the source code of Monotorrent (https://github.com/mono/monotorrent) there is a sample client and tracker all you need to change in the tracker is the code i gave above and create a torrent file with the announce - "udp://Your-IP:Port/announce/" start it with the sample client(I use a similar code in my program) and see that nothing happens(it dosent work) but with utorrent the announce works. 
Thank you for the help :)